# Ordering a Pandas stack groupby output in descending order

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

The sample code below creates a summary.

If is possible to order the numbers associated with each "Type" in the output in descending order?

```
import pandas as pd

dicta={'a':['K','L','K','L','K','L','K','L'],
       'b':['Type_x1','Type_y1','Type_z1','Type_x2','Type_y2','Type_z2','Type_x3','Type_y3'],
       'c':[1,2,None,4,5,6,None,8]}

d=pd.DataFrame(dicta,columns=['a','b','c'])

k=d.pivot(index='a',columns='b',values='c')

k.apply(lambda x : x.name+": "+x.astype(str)).mask(k.isnull()).stack().groupby(level=0).apply(', '.join)
```

Comment: in which output, the final `apply` or the pivot? can you add your desired output

Comment: In the final appy. Can't add a newline, but the output would be ordered by the value associated with the Type:
'Type_y2: 5.0, Type_x1: 1.0'                  
'Type_y3: 8.0, Type_z2: 6.0, Type_x2: 4.0, Type_y1: 2.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort them first before concatenating them.

```
import pandas as pd

dicta={'a':['K','L','K','L','K','L','K','L'],
       'b':['Type_x1','Type_y1','Type_z1','Type_x2','Type_y2','Type_z2','Type_x3','Type_y3'],
       'c':[1,2,None,4,5,6,None,8]}

d=pd.DataFrame(dicta,columns=['a','b','c'])

d = d.dropna().sort_values('c', ascending = False)
d['combined'] = d.apply(lambda x: x.b + ":" + str(x.c), axis = 1)
d.groupby('a')['combined'].agg(','.join)
```